# Retrieving all the possible postal codes with only the street name and country (Germany)

Tags: here-api

Trying to build a dialog with a single text box where a user can (among others) enter just a street name in Germany, and the dialog should then display a list of all the postal codes (PLZ) possible for that street name in the whole of Germany. So basically I would need a list of all the PLZ + street name combinations in Germany ordered by streets in bigger cities first (or bigger streets first, if possible). I Have tried several different HERE APIs, but cannot yield any results when doing a search with only the street name, with country set to Germany. If I additionally fill in the city (streetname + city), then I get a nice response with all I need. So is there any way to get results for queries containing only street name and country (where country='DEU'), and without any city? The search would need to be location agnostic, only assumption being that the user is in Germany.

This kind of minimalistic search seems to work at here.com map site. The only problem on the here.com site is that it's locating me on a wrong city, and thus the 3 results it's giving me are not really relevant for my location. For instance, I'm in Berlin and here.com locates me in Leipzig, and I'm searching with "Chausseestr.".

Any thoughts if an address search with only the street name and country is feasible? 
Thanks!

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to edit your question. While its clear what you are trying to do, its not clear how you are doing things or where you are having trouble. Is it Javascript? Is it database code? Add some source code, state what you are having trouble with, and remove the unneeded explanations. The unneeded explanations just take away from the clarity of the question you have. It makes the post quite difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a **structured Geocoding** request, but unfortunately a `street` only geocoding request is too broad to return a valid response. Neither does a request combining `street` with `country`. Your best bet here would be to split Germany up into a series of non-overlapping [bounding box geocoding requests](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-rest/geocoder/lat-lng-by-mapview-parameter.html) covering say the north-east, north-west and south of the country and to amalgamate the results.

This request looks for *'Hauptstrasse'* in Eastern Germany and returns up to 100 post codes only

[http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?street=hauptstrasse&responseattributes=none&locationattributes=none,ar&app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&gen=3&addressattributes=none,pst&country=deu&mapview=LAT,LONG;LAT,LONG&maxresults=100](http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?street=hauptstrasse&responseattributes=none&locationattributes=none,ar&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=3&addressattributes=none,pst&country=deu&mapview=54.2415,12.0324;50.1901,15.0511&maxresults=100)

- `street` sets the street name to look for,
- `country=deu` restricts the results to Germany
- `responseattributes=none` removes confidence meta info from the response
- `locationattributes=none,ar` restricts the responses to address only
- `addressattributes=none,pst` restricts the addresses to post code only
- `mapview` defines the limit of the bounding box of the request.
- `maxresults=100` ensures up to 100 results are returned.

Repeat this with Western Germany, Southern Germany and so on.

What works for [here.com](http://here.com), and may work for your **dialog box**, is to use the suggestion end point from the [places api](http://developer.here.com/docs/places/). Try making a series of **suggestion** requests as the text box is filled setting the `X-Map-Viewport` to cover Germany :

[http://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/suggest?X-Map-Viewport=LNG,LAT,LNG,LAT&q=haupt&app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&accept=application/json&size=100](http://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/suggest?X-Map-Viewport=5.9845,47.413,14.3671,54.8073&q=haupt&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&accept=application/json&size=100)

There is even a ready made [JavaScript component](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/places-components/custom_template_searchbox.html) which could do this.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered just try the geocoding ? and not taking just the first result, I would suppose this is what you see on the service example you are refering to. Thus do actually loop through all of replies. Of course see the API you are using, and make sure you are setting some nice number for the max results before doing any queries.

At least in some HERE offerings the reply data also includes address, thus you could fetch the postal code from there.

Also if it is not there, then do revercegeo query with the location gotten, then at least you should be getting it

Answer (score 0):

Never too late to answer such a question.

1. Install QGIS (free).
2. Then `"Plugins"` -> `"Manage and install plugins..."` -> install `"OSMDownloader"`
3. Then `"Vector"` -> `"Openstreetmap"` -> `"Download data"` after you've zoomed into the area of interest

When you have the `.xml` file, use simple unix command line utils to slice and dice accordingly.

Quick hack (bit of a caveman solution but worked for me):

```
$ grep -A1 'addr:post' OSM_input.xml | egrep -v '^--$' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'  | grep 'addr:street' | awk -F'v="' '{print$2"#"$3}' | sed 's/"\/>     <tag k="addr:street" //' | sed 's/"\/>/,/' > output.txt
```

The `output.txt` will contain a mostly accurate (needs some manual cleanup) file whose format is: `zipcode#streetname` (one per line).